# Rentry to numpy function returns Error: float object has no attribute exp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I finally figured out why I was getting a "weird" error in a function call.  But I do not understand WHY I got the error or how to avoid it in the future.

The error was:

```
rates  = Qi*np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))
```

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

This question was asked over 5 years ago ([Numpy AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557337/numpy-attributeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-exp) and it is similar to [Different behavior of arithmetics on dtype float 'object' and 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662823/different-behavior-of-arithmetics-on-dtype-float-object-and-float)), but neither answer tells me how to arbitrarily avoid the problem.

I am using pandas and numpy.  The function is called as follows:

```
df3['Model_EXP'], df3['Model_EXPcum'] =arps.arps(days = df3[dayscol], Qi=parmexp[0], Di=parmexp[1], T0=parmexp[2])
```

where df3 is a dataframe, the column df3[dayscol] is a column of type int64, and parmexp is a tuple containing parameters for the function.

The function was originally written for numpy (not pandas) and expects numpy vectors.  The start of the function def is as follows:

```
def arps(days = None, Qi = None, Di = None, Bi = 0., T0=None, DTMIN=-5., QMIN = 1., Oil=True):
   if (not Di or not Qi):
      print("Nominal Decline or Rate not entered in routine arps.  Stopping.")
      sys.exit()
   if (np.isnan(np.sum(days))):
          print("Error in days passed to routine arps.  Some non-days in vector.  Stopping.")
      sys.exit()
   if (Di < 0.):
      Di = -1.*Di                                         # just in case someone got their signs wrong
   #
   rates   = np.zeros(len(days))
   cums    = np.zeros(len(days))
   dtval   = np.zeros(len(days))
   if (T0 == None):
      T0 = days[0]
   if (Bi == 0.):                                             #  Exponential Decline
      rates  = Qi*np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))                       #  THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET INTERESTING
```

I have called this function multiple times in my application.  It had always worked.  I added another function to call this routine with another dataframe.  However, even though this works during the same execution, I started getting the following error:

```
  File "...Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "decline_curve_analysis.py", line 993, in predpred
    df3['Model_EXP'], df3['Model_EXPcum'] =arps.arps(days = df3[dayscol], Qi=parmexp[0], Di=parmexp[1], T0=parmexp[2])
  File "...\PetroPy\DeclineCurves.py", line 110, in arps
    rates  = Qi*np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

I didn't understand why, so I printed out the dataframe just before the function call.  The "dayscol" column had different values, but in both working and non-working cases the days vector (which is the df3[dayscol] column) in "int64".  However, when I made the following change in the called function:

```
      print("Type of days",days.dtype)
      newexp = (-Di*(days-T0))
      print("Type of newexp",newexp.dtype)
      rates  = Qi*np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))                       #  THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET INTERESTING
```

I discovered that I got the following response on the calls which worked:

```
   Type of days int64
   Type of newexp float64
```

but got the following for those which failed:

```
   Type of days int64
   Type of newexp object
```

which I've now solved by rewriting my original function to be:

```
      newexp = (-Di*(days-T0))
      newexp = newexp.astype(np.float64)
      rates  = Qi*np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))                       #  THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET INTERESTING
```

QUESTION:

Is there a way I can ensure that this doesn't occur again?  It's taken me over a day to debug this, and I'm concerned because I have a lot of non-pandas functions that I don't want to fail when I use them in other projects.  Is this even related to the way the function is called?

Thanks.

Comment: `pandas` readily produces object dtype series.  When you use code like this you need to test dtype of the arguments, and if possible convert them a numeric dtype.

Comment: I haven't used `pandas` enough to know why or when it switches to object dtype.  String elements in a series seem to do it.  Rather than make the whole series string (as `np.array` would) it goes the mixed object route.  `None` or `nan` values might also do it (even though `nan` is a float).

Answer (score -2):

The underlying type of a numpy array can not be devised.

Python is only **dynamically strongly typed** ([Is Python strongly typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed)  )

**That's it's main strength and one of it's main frustrating weakness.**

There is no real way around it in your case. In some case you can [Force a function parameter type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858192/force-a-function-parameter-type-in-python)  but in your case you can not specify the underlying type in numpy.ndarray.

What is troubling is

> It's taken me over a day to debug this

error should tip you off to directly check the types in line 110

> File "...\PetroPy\DeclineCurves.py", line 110, in arps
>     rates  = Qi * np.exp(-Di*(days-T0))
>   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

Oh I get it big data, slow loading time,... Well check your code when you use transcendental functions.